# Wrong timestamp in Android Notification

Tags: android, notifications, timestamp

In the bottom right corner of my standard Android notification I will not see time (eg 12:00) rather than a pattern like that: 11/1/16. Always 3 numbers diveded by "/". Anybody know the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't khow, how you make your notification but i think you should use : System.currentTimeMillis()

**Example :**

```
package com.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class TestActivity extends Activity {

    private NotificationManager notificationManager;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        showNotification("My notification",android.R.id.text1);
    }

    private void showNotification(CharSequence text, int idNotify) {
      Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, text, System.currentTimeMillis());
      Intent intent = new Intent();
      intent.setClassName("com.test","com.test.TestActivity");
      PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(TestActivity.this, 0,intent,0);
      notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, "My Notification",text, contentIntent);
      notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
      notificationManager.notify(idNotify, notification);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I have multiplied the currentTimeMillis() by 1000. That was the problem!

Comment: Now, I have accepted it:-) Did not know how to do, since I am new here.